# Error 3221225477 - Fresh instaltion Visual studio Code

Tags: c++, debugging, segmentation-fault

I having a problem with visual studio code, that i cant run C++ prorams.
I'm just started studyding programing some weeks ago, and trying some IDE's.

I can run C programs normally wit VSC, only C++ are geting the erro bellow.
(It's a very simple program that i create just to test if its ok, and nothing worked).
G++ version 13.2.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    std::cout << "teste";
    return 0;
}
```

Print of the erros, and debug is attached.

On output, its informed:
`[Done] exited with code=3221225477 in 0.431 seconds`
(Just the error that informed, Segmentation fault)

I know that can be some configuration problem...
I used CodeLite and its works with the this version of G++.
Visual Studio works too.

Is there anything I can do to make it work?

I see that is a error with memory alocation... But, i dint did a complex code with something to mess up it...
So, i did some others tests with numbers opeations, inputs, and the result is the same.

Comment: You are in dll hell condition.

Comment: ***I used CodeLite and its works with the this version of G++*** This is probably the 
 cause of the problem. You likely have multiple incompatible versions of MinGW in your windows `PATH` environment variable. My advice to fix this is to remove all versions of MinGW you have installed and do what the [vscode MinGW instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) tell you and install msys2 and have that install MinGW.